# Maven build - dependancy on core classes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have two projects I am working on which share some common code - I am putting this common code in to a new project called Core.

Both my projects use maven to build, and my core classes will also use maven. In Eclipse how do I configure maven to do a maven build of the core classes and then use these in the build for my two other applications?

Is there some prebuilt rule I need to specify - for example build this project, however, go build core first and use the output of that for this.

Hope that makes some sort of sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dependency to Core artifact in your project.

If you use [M2E Eclipse plug-in](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), workspace artifacts are quite easy to reference in the Maven editor.

The only condition for this kind of dependency to work is that dependent artifact must be retrievable from a maven repository (eventually putting it to the local maven repository through `install` goal).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a parent pom, with modules

```
<project>
    <groupId>com.mypackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>parent</name> 
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
...
<modules>
  <module>Core</module>
  <module>MyModuleA</module>
  <module>MyModuleB</module>
</modules>
...
</project>
```

And then just add your dependency in MyModuleA and MyModuleB like a normal dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mypackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>Core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: so i assume the parent pom would be my core pom?

Comment: No, it just goes one level up from your three projects.  When you build your parent project, it will force the children (Core first) to build as well

Comment: To have the correct build order as the OP requested, it's not mandatory to have artifacts as modules of a parent pom. You can also have dependencies among artifacts not in the same parent pom.

Comment: If you didn't have a parent pom, you would have to manually build in a specific order, though, correct?

Comment: Correct. Unless you use it with a plug-in, as I suggested. The Maven Eclipse plug-in is able to manage the build order. I thought about Eclipse because the OP tagged the question as related to Eclipse.